# PHP Fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found - My Php Version is 7.0.17

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I Developed One Laravel Project. In local System Its working Fine. When i move the Project to the Server. Its Return Following Error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line 18
```

My PHP Version is 7.0.17. How to Fix this Issue.

**Collection.php**

```
use Countable;
use Exception;
use ArrayAccess;
use Traversable;
use ArrayIterator;
use CachingIterator;
use JsonSerializable;
use IteratorAggregate;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;

class Collection implements ArrayAccess, Arrayable, Countable, IteratorAggregate, Jsonable, JsonSerializable
{
    use Macroable;
    .....................
    ......................
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more information on your code and your setup to gain a more detailed answer. The error is quite clear to what the issue is.

Comment: Post all of your code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: If you post a question and people ask for clarifications and you fail to provide them you're just inviting yourself to downvotes and getting your question closed.

Comment: Error Displayed on Laravel core Files @StevenDavison

Comment: 1) Search the code in the copy that works to find the file that contains the `JsonSerializable` interface. 2) Compare with the copy that doesn't work. Does the file exist on both? If not, congratulations: you've found the problem. Now try to work out why. Composer might be helpful here. If it does exist, why is not auto-loading? Again, look to Composer for an answer.

Comment: That update doesn't tell me about your system. I think the process @Simba advises to attain the resolution will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your Php info Settings, Json is Enabled.

Comment: I dont think its that easy.  Im using 5.6, its supposed to be bundled with it, it says its `enabled` and version is `1.2.1`, yet composer installing laravelcollective/html says Interface 'JsonSerilizable' not found.  Do i need to possibly enable it in laravel somehow?

Comment: @blamb please were you able to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the setup between local and server is different.

Ensure that the resources you are referencing are available to the server in the same location as the local.