# Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am getting `Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found error` in my site.

I am using `Laravel 5.4` and `PHP 7.1.13`.

`JSON module` is also enabled in `Cpanel`.

But still i am getting following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in
>   /******/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 22
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in
>   /******/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php
>   on line 17

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The`JsonSerializable` interface is a builtin PHP interface and to access it from a namespace, it has to be used as `\JsonSerializable` unless it's been imported using the `use JsonSerializable;`

Comment: What is your `php` version on server?

Comment: use JsonSerializable; line is already added.

Comment: Version : PHP 7.1.13

Comment: @TheAlpha Those are framework files, there's no way it's an import error.

Comment: @JoelHinz, I know so asked about the version.

Answer (score 1):

> Check your Php info Settings, Json is Enabled.

[PHP Fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found - My Php Version is 7.0.17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363108/php-fatal-error-interface-jsonserializable-not-found-my-php-version-is-7-0/43366188)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem in my Cpanel. When I upgrade the PHP version of my Cpanel `MultiPHP Manager`, it works fine.

Upgrade PHP version `7.4 to 8.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on cpanel, I solved it by changing the php version from 7.3 to 7.4 under `MultiPHP Manager`.

~regards