# Getting HTTP ERROR 500 With Interface JsonSerializable Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, laravel-8

I have uploaded my Laravel 8 project to server, and when I refresh the page I get this error:

```
This page isn’t working mydomain.com 
is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

And when I checkout `public_html/error_logs` I see this:

```
[07-Jun-2021 13:11:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in /home/domainname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Enumerable.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /home/domainname/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#1 /home/domainname/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/domainname/...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')
#3 /home/domainname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php(11): spl_autoload_call('Illuminate\\Supp...')
#4 /home/domainname/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include('/home/domainname/...')
#5 /home/domainname/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/domainname/...')
#6 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')
#7 /home/domainname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php(15): spl_autoload_call('Illuminate\\Supp...')
#8 /home/domainname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support in /home/domainname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Enumerable.php on line 11
[07-Jun-2021 13:11:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in /home/domainname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Enumerable.php:11
```

So what is going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465990/interface-jsonserializable-not-found

Comment: if you have sudo rights on the server, check the php.ini in the cli version and verify that the json extention is enabled. if it is missing, install the php-json extention. If you dont know what i'm talking about, contact your system administrator or the support of your provider

Answer (score 0):

JSON is probably not active in the particular version of PHP. Make sure the server version of PHP includes JSON support.

Comment: How to make sure that php version of server supports JSON >

Comment: I think it's available out of the box on many version you'll need PHP >= 5.2.0 at least. But Laravel has minimum requirements on PHP version anyway. so check that first.